How do you set up Drush Aliases in DDEV?
We are slowly moving to DDEV for our local development environments and so far so good. I am sure the following is a really common usecase, hence the question.
I have tried just about everything but cannot seem to get Drush Aliases working on my DDEV set up. I always get this on a drush sa:
 [success] No site aliases found.

I have added a folder (.drush/sites) and have my remote aliases listed in a self.site.yml as follows:
---
dev:
  root: /var/www/dev/web
  uri: https://mydev.mysite.org.uk

uat:
  root: /var/www/uat/web
  uri: https://myuat.mysite.org.uk

live:
  root: /var/www/prod/web
  uri: https://mylive.mysite.org.uk

The path to this alias file is defined in the ProjectDir/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml:
drush:
  php:
    minimum-version: 8.1.0
  paths:
    alias-path:
      - '${env.HOME}/.drush/sites'
      - '/var/www/html/.drush/sites'

I have tried to both reference a local file and a location on my host machine. Interestingly, when I ssh into the container and do a which drush, I get this:
/var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush

On my host machine where aliases do work, the location is:
/home/myuser/vendor/drush/drush/drush

So is this the issue?
The only thing I can find that I think is relevent is How can I get my drush aliases into the DDEV web container but this not worked for me either.
How do I point Drush to the correct aliases path?

That worked perfectly, thank you so much.  I had tried this in my various attempts - I must have messed something up....  I'm still not sure why I cannot define a path to the alias like I usually can, but I'll worry about that another day!

Following the instructions at https://www.drush.org/12.x/site-aliases/ and placing the YAML file in $PROJECT/drush/sites/self.site.yml you can execute vendor/bin/drush sa outside the container and you can ddev ssh to the web container and execute drush sa or vendor/bin/drush sa and all these commands show the defined Drush aliases.
